'tri jardekojn' as an advervial phrase?
I saw a sentence
Mi laboris en la sama oficejo tri jardekojn.

Here 'tri jardekojn' means 'for three decades' which is an advervial phrase in English.
I wonder why it is written as if it were an objective using -n ending.

La finaĵo -n povas montri plurajn aferojn:

objekton (mi manĝas pomon)
mezuron (mi staris kelkajn paŝojn for de la grupo)
direkton (mi iras tien)
...

En via demando, tiu -n priskribas mezuron tempan. Jen ekzemplo el Fundamenta Krestomatio (pere de tekstaro.com):
La virino tri horojn estis kontenta

