on the twentieth (date) --> la dudekan
I was asked to translate Sofia traveled to Russia on the twentieth of June. My answer was Sofia vojaĝis al Rusio la dudeka de junio. but
dudeka should have been dudekan.
Dudeka does not seem to be an objective and I thought there should be some preposition such as on in English.
What am I mistaken?

Tiu ĉi respondo rilatas la plursignifan -n finaĵon: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/tri-jardekojn-as-an-advervial-phrase (unu el el signifoj estas "tempopunkto").

You can think of -n as a special preposition. Its main usage is "direct object" but another meaning is exactly that: an ending for dates ("on" in English). You could use another preposition such as "dum", "en", "je" etc. but -n is the most common one for dates while "je" is the most common for time.


Sofia vojaĝis al Rusio je la dudeka de junio.


Sofia vojaĝis al Rusio la dudekan de junio.

Here on is precisely translated as je. An accusative is possible too (no preposition and no subject of the phrase).
The English place before time is a matter what you want to stress in Esperanto.

Sofia vojaĝis je la dudeka de junio al Rusio.


Actually the order of the time and the place reference depends on what the topic and the comment of your sentence are. Here, does the sentence answers the question "where did Sofia travelled on the twentieth of June?" or "when did Sofia travelled to Russia?" The answering part, new info, or the comment should become last in the sentence. For further info read the letter Pri vortordo en Esperanto by AdE.

@JuhaMetsäkallas thanks, actually you provide valuable info on the order in Esperanto. I wanted to state that the order in English favors place before time. Hence an Esperanto translation can be more precise. One should not necessarily keep the same order.
